# Ruby "Mail" gem docs

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mail-gem

I can't find the full documentation of the Mail gem https://github.com/mikel/mail

For the documentation, all links are to the main github page, but the readme is far from complete. Is there any alternative to search everything in the source code?

Comment: The README is pretty good, but where it hasn't included what I need, I've just dived into the code, which is pretty well laid out.

Comment: I dived into the code too for now, but it is very unconvenient. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can also view the rdoc documentation on ruby-doc.org and on the yard site. http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/m/mail-2.4.4/ and http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/frames

Comment: Thank you @d11wtq ! I solved the immediate problem, but that was exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @d11wtq in the comments above you can find the rdoc documentation on [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/m/mail-2.5.4/) and [rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/frames)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the gem with the documentation, you could run a local gem documentation server by running:

```
gem server
```

It will tell you where it's accessible.  Connect with your web browser and look for the mail gem.  There's more documentation there.